# Hint on how to obtain reduction formula for the following integral?

Tags: integration

$$\int\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{2ax-x^2}}dx$$
I have no idea where to start. I tried integration by parts but it wasn't helpful.

Correct answer given in textbook is:

$$nI_{n}=-x^n(2ax-x)/\sqrt{2ax-x^2}+(2n-I)aI_{n-1}$$

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see any $n$ in your first integral. Did you make a typo? Usually it is best to provide reasonable context in your questions to allow people to help you accordingly. Questions which are just problem statements are discouraged here.

Comment: No, it isn't  a typo. It is written that way in my textbook. I would have provided more context if I had a clue how to solve the question. But I'm clueless. I tried integration by parts, but it didn't match the answer.

Comment: If that's the case why do you a need a reduction formula? Also that integral in beginning is a very routine one. Use the techniques given in your textbook which deal with integrals of functions like $\sqrt {ax^2+bx+c}$.

Comment: You can write $2ax-x^2=a^2-(a-x)^2$ and use the substitution $a-x=a\sin t$. Proceed with this hint and update your question with your effort.

Comment: Was there another part/context preceding this question? Check if you're being asked to find a reduction formula for something like:

 $I_n = \displaystyle \int\frac{x^n\,\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{2ax-x^2}}.$

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I was asked to find the redction formula otherwise I wouldn't have asked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note

\begin{align} 
I_n=& \int \frac{x^n}{\sqrt{2ax-x^2} }dx\\
=& \int \frac{x^{n-2}(x^2-2ax)+2ax^{n-1}}{\sqrt{2ax-x^2} }dx
=-\int x^{n-2}\sqrt{2ax-x^2} dx+2a I_{n-1}\\
 =& -\frac1{n-1}\int\sqrt{2ax-x^2} \>d(x^{n-1})+2a I_{n-1}\\
=& -\frac1{n-1}x^{n-1}\sqrt{2ax-x^2} + \frac 1{n-1}(aI_{n-1}- I_n )+2aI_{n-1}\\
\end{align}
which leads to the reduction formula
$$nI_n = -x^{n-1}\sqrt{2ax-x^2} +a(2n-1)I_{n-1}
$$
Then, set $n=2$ to get

\begin{align} \int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{2ax-x^2} }dx
 =& -\frac x2\sqrt{2ax-x^2} +\frac{3a}2\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{2ax-x^2} }dx
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time and answering my question. Thanks again.